# Outlook 2013 asking for administrator after Compatibility change (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, compatibility

I have a machine with `Windows 8.1` and `Office 2013` installed, which I wanted to change the compatibility to Windows Vista.

The problem is, when Windows 8.1 have a pre-installed application into it, it does not let you directly change the compatibility, so it does not show the compatibility tab on properties of the .exe, which is the outlook.exe case.

With that in mind I used ''solve compatibility problems'' to change the compatibility. It asks you to use an administrator account, so I let the user as admin to execute this task, worked fine and them I removed it from admin.

There is the huge problem, now the Outlook asks every time I open for administrator account, I can not let her as admin because she is a user and neither use my account to authenticate every time she opens outlook.

Does anyone have an idea of how can I change that? I know that in Windows 7 it would be just open properties and uncheck ''run as administrator'' but there is no kind of that option on ''solve compatibility problems''

I have already tried to change back to Windows 8 but it still asking. I do not wanted to do a System restore into a previous state because it is really old.

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you want to change compatibility in the first place? What are you hoping to achieve? Compatibility is designed to try to let older, unsupported apps run in something closer to their native environment.

Comment: My user wanted to change where the Outlook desktop alert was showing (on Windows 8/8.1 this can not be changed), so when you change the compatibility to Windows Vista or Windows 7, the option automatically reappears and you can redefine those options!

Answer (score 0):

After a huge research, I finally found the solution of this error as the same solution for another problem.

The solution below for those with the same problem:

- Right-Click on the executable
- Choose `"Troubleshoot compatibility"`
- Click `"Troubleshoot program"`
- Uncheck any and all checked items
- Click `"Next"`
- Choose `"No, I have finished investigating the problem - undo any changes made and clear all settings"`
- Click `"Next"`
- Click `"Close the troubleshooter"`